# How to present a controller in a specific area of the screen in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have two controller in the screen as the pic shows.
now I wanna present the ThirdViewController in the red area when the tableView is selected, I try to use present() but it shows in the whole screen. how Can I fix that?[image]

Comment: Try to add it as a childViewController. "self.addChildViewController(firstVC)"

Comment: its really a bad way to ask a question over here, please follow the standards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Download 3 files from Folder **Presentation**

Add this to the VC from which you will open Second VC

```
lazy var slideInTransitioningDelegate = SlideInPresentationManager()
```

**When going to another VC;**

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Ident") as? YourViewController
 vc?.delegate = self
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)

slideInTransitioningDelegate.direction = .bottom // or .left, .right
slideInTransitioningDelegate.disableCompactHeight = true
navigationController.transitioningDelegate = slideInTransitioningDelegate
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Tutorial** - https://www.raywenderlich.com/915-uipresentationcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

**Project** - https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/08/Medal_Count_Completed.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first adding your SecondViewController into you MainViewController as child controller and then add SecondViewController's view as subview in `UITableViewCell`.

```
var secondViewController : SecondViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    self.addChildViewController(setupProfileViewController)

}
```

Now somewhere in your code when you want to show that SecondViewController view controller like on `didSelectRowAt indexPath` method of `UITableViewCell` or any other button action, add following line of code:

```
let cell = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath)
cell.contentView.addSubview(secondViewController.view)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no image attached, so I am not sure what exactly you want; but to show a view controller in area of another view controller, you could use container view, this is a useful tutorial about [container view](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/custom-container-view-controllers-in-swift)

and to load by some action, you could present your container view when your action done.